# Even though it is in conancenter, it gives an error

Tags: c++, cmake, conan

I'm trying to make a very simple example using **Conan**. Here are my steps:

#### Directory Structure

```
.
├── build
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── conanfile.txt
└── main.cpp
```

#### main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <curl/curl.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

#### conanfile.txt

```
[requires]
libcurl/7.77.0

[generators]
CMakeDeps
CMakeToolchain
```

#### CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(Conan2 CXX)

find_package(CURL CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(App main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(App CURL::libcurl)
```

```
$ cd build
$ conan install ..

======== Input profiles ========
Profile host:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu14
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=9
os=Linux

Profile build:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.cppstd=gnu14
compiler.libcxx=libstdc++11
compiler.version=9
os=Linux


======== Computing dependency graph ========
Graph root
    conanfile.txt: /home/qwe/NoteX/Conan/2/conanfile.txt
Requirements
    libcurl/7.77.0#fa792ade05b92058672e6fc91d442ffb - Cache
    openssl/3.1.3#fff5e82eb893e0c6ab135df0e60b894f - Cache
    zlib/1.2.13#97d5730b529b4224045fe7090592d4c1 - Cache
Build requirements
    autoconf/2.71#53be95d228b2dcb30dc199cb84262d8f - Cache
    automake/1.16.5#058bda3e21c36c9aa8425daf3c1faf50 - Cache
    gnu-config/cci.20210814#15c3bf7dfdb743977b84d0321534ad90 - Cache
    libtool/2.4.7#d55a3c2435c19e830fa77aa5c6c19350 - Cache
    m4/1.4.19#adbdd7fb7db33e609425c797196baccb - Cache
    meson/1.2.2#aace9dcc1db58fa42ecb5292f724092d - Cache
    ninja/1.11.1#77587f8c8318662ac8e5a7867eb4be21 - Cache
    pkgconf/1.9.3#3e658ebc066dc868a1f8a472c1065368 - Cache
Resolved version ranges
    openssl/[>=1.1 <4]: openssl/3.1.3

======== Computing necessary packages ========
Requirements
    libcurl/7.77.0#fa792ade05b92058672e6fc91d442ffb:a66c168cd0b825324f775fad7b3886c2d22225c3 - Missing
    openssl/3.1.3#fff5e82eb893e0c6ab135df0e60b894f:2b010f4baf8e367a9e2df7f714b35852aa8fa5aa - Missing
    zlib/1.2.13#97d5730b529b4224045fe7090592d4c1:72c852c5f0ae27ca0b1741e5fd7c8b8be91a590a - Missing
Build requirements
Skipped binaries
    autoconf/2.71, automake/1.16.5, gnu-config/cci.20210814, libtool/2.4.7, m4/1.4.19, meson/1.2.2, ninja/1.11.1, pkgconf/1.9.3

======== Installing packages ========
ERROR: Missing binary: libcurl/7.77.0:a66c168cd0b825324f775fad7b3886c2d22225c3
ERROR: Missing binary: openssl/3.1.3:2b010f4baf8e367a9e2df7f714b35852aa8fa5aa
ERROR: Missing binary: zlib/1.2.13:72c852c5f0ae27ca0b1741e5fd7c8b8be91a590a

zlib/1.2.13: WARN: Can't find a 'zlib/1.2.13' package binary '72c852c5f0ae27ca0b1741e5fd7c8b8be91a590a' for the configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=9
os=Linux
[options]
fPIC=True
shared=False

ERROR: Missing prebuilt package for 'libcurl/7.77.0', 'openssl/3.1.3', 'zlib/1.2.13'
Check the available packages using 'conan list zlib/1.2.13:* -r=remote'
or try to build locally from sources using the '--build=libcurl/7.77.0 --build=openssl/3.1.3 --build=zlib/1.2.13' argument

More Info at 'https://docs.conan.io/2/knowledge/faq.html#error-missing-prebuilt-package'
```

Lets check Are there really these packages in ConanCenter or not?

```
$ conan search zlib/1.2.13 -r=conancenter
conancenter
  zlib
    zlib/1.2.13
$ conan search openssl/3.1.3 -r=conancenter
conancenter
  openssl
    openssl/3.1.3
```

As you can see with the search command above, it gives the error below even though it is in conancenter.

ERROR: Missing prebuilt package for 'libcurl/7.77.0', 'openssl/3.1.3', 'zlib/1.2.13'
Check the available packages using 'conan list zlib/1.2.13:* -r=remote'
or try to build locally from sources using the '--build=libcurl/7.77.0 --build=openssl/3.1.3 --build=zlib/1.2.13' argument

More Info at 'https://docs.conan.io/2/knowledge/faq.html#error-missing-prebuilt-package'

#### First Edit

When i build manually, it gives another error.

```
$ conan install .. --build=libcurl/7.77.0 --build=openssl/3.1.3 --
build=zlib/1.2.13


======== Installing packages ========
ERROR: Missing binary: libtool/2.4.7:72c852c5f0ae27ca0b1741e5fd7c8b8be91a590a

libtool/2.4.7: WARN: Can't find a 'libtool/2.4.7' package binary '72c852c5f0ae27ca0b1741e5fd7c8b8be91a590a' for the configuration:
[settings]
arch=x86_64
build_type=Release
compiler=gcc
compiler.version=9
os=Linux
[options]
fPIC=True
shared=False

ERROR: Missing prebuilt package for 'libtool/2.4.7'
Check the available packages using 'conan list libtool/2.4.7:* -r=remote'
or try to build locally from sources using the '--build=libtool/2.4.7' argument

More Info at 'https://docs.conan.io/2/knowledge/faq.html#error-missing-prebuilt-package'
```

#### Second edit

After build manually it compiles fine. After compiling what i done:

```
$ cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake -DCMAKE_POLICY_DEFAULT_CMP0091=NEW -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
$ cmake --build . --config Release
```

After above commands I was able to create the executable file successfully.

Comment: The error message gives you a command to fix the problem, did you try using that? The recipes are available, the binaries for your configuration aren't

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, now it gives another error. why do i need to build locally? Why doesn't it just download what I need?

Comment: most probably it will work when i build locally libtool

Comment: because they don't build for every possible compiler, operating system and configuration. Just add `--build=missing` to your command line and it'll just work every time. This is all explained in the documentation which again is linked from the error message

Comment: @AlanBirtles thanks for your answer.  why The files created after this command => "conan install .. --build=libcurl/7.77.0 " were created in a parent folder, not in the build folder. (i wrote this command in build directory)Also now i can create executable file, i also edited my question showing how to create my executable file. do you think it is ok?

Comment: It outputs to the directory containing the Conan file by default, there's a command line option to change that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Conan [install](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/commands/install.html)  command is showing your dependencies graph:

```
======== Computing dependency graph ========
Graph root
    conanfile.txt: /home/qwe/NoteX/Conan/2/conanfile.txt
Requirements
    libcurl/7.77.0#fa792ade05b92058672e6fc91d442ffb - Cache
    openssl/3.1.3#fff5e82eb893e0c6ab135df0e60b894f - Cache
    zlib/1.2.13#97d5730b529b4224045fe7090592d4c1 - Cache
```

And it says that you have those packages recipes cached already.

So, Conan will try to find a binary package with a [package ID](https://docs.conan.io/2/tutorial/consuming_packages/different_configurations.html#introducing-the-concept-of-package-id) that matches your current [profile](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/config_files/profiles.html)

By default, Conan will use your cache to find that package, but as it does not exist in your machine, it will result on [missing dependencies error](https://docs.conan.io/2/knowledge/faq.html#error-missing-prebuilt-package). But you still can tell to Conan to use a remote as priority, instead of your cache, to look for that missing binary package. To do that, you need to pass `--remote=<remote_name>`:

```
conan install --requires=zlib/1.3 -r conancenter
# or
conan install conanfile.txt -r conancenter
```

Here I told to Conan: Try to install `zlib/1.3` from `conancenter` first. Or, try to install anything listed in `conanfile.txt` from the `conancenter` first.

It should solve your case, because Conan Center does support GCC9, as listed in the [supported configurations](https://github.com/conan-io/conan-center-index/blob/master/docs/supported_platforms_and_configurations.md)

---

About your second situation:

```
When i build manually, it gives another error.

$ conan install .. --build=libcurl/7.77.0 --build=openssl/3.1.3 --
build=zlib/1.2.13


======== Installing packages ========
ERROR: Missing binary: libtool/2.4.7:72c852c5f0ae27ca0b1741e5fd7c8b8be91a590a
```

Conan uses a dependencies graph to decide its build order, but when you said to build those packages, the `libtool` is also listed in the graph and is missing too. To check the build order executed to build a package, you can run [graph build-order](https://docs.conan.io/2/reference/commands/graph/build_order.html) command:

```
conan graph build-order --requires=libcurl/7.77.0
```

However, it could be boring solving all this, as you actually just want to install a package. So, to solve it automatically, you can pass `--build=missing`. The `missing` is a special word, that tells Conan to build what is missing in the graph only. But in case you want to build everything from source, you actually can pass `--build=*`:

```
conan install conanfile.txt --build=missing --remote=conancenter
```

This command should solve your problem. It will install from Conan Center first, then what it does not find available, Conan will build from sources automatically.

Comment: why The files created after this command => "conan install .. --build=libcurl/7.77.0 " were created in a parent folder, not in the build folder. Can you show me also how to fix this. thanks